# How do you describe a word that has two, conflicting meanings depending on the context?

Tags: single-word-requests, context

There is a single word that can be used to describe these, and I'm having trouble remembering it. I think it might be a '*-nym*' word or a '*-phone*', but I can't remember.

An example would be **handicap**, which can be used to describe an *advantage* or a *disadvantage*, depending on the context.

Comment: Aside: a [**handicap**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/handicap) is a disadvantage, not an advantage. A golfer's handicap is used to disadvantage them in play, although it may be used to express how good a player is.

Comment: A better example might be "to cleave" = (i) to split [something] apart (ii) to adhere tightly [to something]. More examples at https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-1365,00.html

Answer (score 0):

A **contronym** (or **contranym**) is a word that can have opposite meanings. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/contronym) has

> **contronym**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A word with two opposite meanings, e.g. sanction (which can mean both ‘a penalty for disobeying a law’ and ‘official permission or approval for an action’).

Some example sentences might be

> We have decided to sanction Countranomia for its illegal actions by ceasing trade.
>
> We have decided to sanction aid for Countranomia because of the famine.

Answer (score 0):

> An **auto-antonym** or **autantonym**, also called a contronym, contranym or **Janus word**, is a word with multiple meanings (senses) of which one is the reverse of another. For example, the word cleave can mean "to cut apart" or "to bind together". This phenomenon is called enantiosemy, enantionymy (enantio- means "opposite"), antilogy or autantonymy. An enantiosemic term is necessarily polysemic.
>
> The terms "autantonym" and "contronym" were coined by Joseph Twadell Shipley in 1960 and Jack Herring in 1962, respectively. An auto-antonym is alternatively called an antagonym, Janus word (after the Roman god Janus, who is usually depicted with two faces),

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym